# Debug unmanaged code in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like to change a debug setting on VS 2012 project to allow for unmanaged code debugging. If I look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I find that there are only articles to enable this for Visual Studio 2010, 2008, and 2005. I am running into an [AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437760/accessviolationexception-was-unhandled) attempting run a third party code, and it appears that the unmanaged code may be causing the problem.

My question is: does Visual Studio 2012 have an option to enable debugging unmanaged code? If not, is this option built-in/hardcoded to be either enabled or disabled?

**EDIT**

This is for an ASP MVC solution. Here's a screen shot of the options from the properties window for my project.

[image]

And here are the properties for the solution

[image]

**Web Properties**

[image]

Comment: in web projects it is on the web tab, bottom section about debuggers, see my answer below

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Have shown that it is not explicitly obvious where this is located. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: probably because it isn't directly programming related, it's more a tools thing?  *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

depending on the project, the places are a little different.

for some, right click the project file, properties, debug tab, I believe there's a setting there for managed/mixed/native only, etc (maybe a dropdown?)

for some, it is the debug tab, and there's an "enable debuggers" section with checkboxes for native/managed/sql/etc

if it is a web project, it is in the **web** tab of the properties, with checkboxes for managed/native/sql/script/etc at the bottom

Comment: I have an "Options and Setting" item in the Debug drop-down, however nothing in "Debuggin" section there about unmanaged code. Could they be calling something else?

Comment: Just added a screen shot of the Web properties tab. Native code is the only checkbox I see down there. Is this what I'm looking for to debug unmanaged code?

Answer (score 0):

For C# Projects, you go to the properties for the project.

Under the Debug tab, there is an "Enable Debuggers" section, which has an "Enable native code debugging" checkbox.

Comment: Just posted a screen shot. That's exactly where I expected it to be, however for this project it's missing.